# Translating C# to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, axios

I am working on a project for a client and need to convert this api call to Javascript.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://stagingapi.asapconnected.com/api/login");

request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "user=username&organizationId=id&password=password&apiKey=apikey");

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()

string accessToken = response.Headers["asap_accesstoken"];
```

My attempt translated into AXIOS get request:

```
axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.asapconnected.com/api/login'
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'user=org***&password=*******&organizationId=*****',
  }
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Keep getting an error:

```
OPTIONS https://api.asapconnected.com/api/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: probably a CORS issue - I see you don't include `apiKey` in your javascript attempt - but yeah ... `OPTIONS` is a CORS preflight, which the other end doesn't handle, (or does, by shutting down the connection abruptly?) - you can't do this from a "client" (browser)

Comment: they didnt require an apikey. I am going to try this from the server side and see if i get any luck.

Comment: the apikey things was an afterthought, the issue is CORS related